# Changing PHP drop-down to UL LI list

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a Wordpress site which has a drop-down/select list for ordering products.

I'd really like to style this nicely and have found a pretty good set of styles [courtesy of codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/) I'd like to use.

However the HTML for this uses UL LI list rather than the standard select.

I need to try and convert the following code:

```
<select name="orderby" class="orderby">
    <?php
        $catalog_orderby = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', array(
            'menu_order' => __( 'Default sorting', 'woocommerce' ),

        'popularity' => __( 'Sort by popularity', 'woocommerce' ),

        'rating'     => __( 'Sort by average rating', 'woocommerce' ),

        'date'       => __( 'Sort by newness', 'woocommerce' ),

        'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),

        'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );

    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) == 'no' )
        unset( $catalog_orderby['rating'] );

    foreach ( $catalog_orderby as $id => $name )
        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" ' . selected( $orderby, $id, false ) . '>' . esc_attr( $name ) . '</option>';
?>
```

into something resembling this:

```
<div class="wrapper-dropdown">
    <span>I'm kinda the label!</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>I'm hidden!</li>
        <li>Me too!</li>
        <li>So do I.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="wrapper-dropdown">
    <span>I'm kinda the label!</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <?php
        $catalog_orderby = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', array(
            'menu_order' => __( 'Default sorting', 'woocommerce' ),

        'popularity' => __( 'Sort by popularity', 'woocommerce' ),

        'rating'     => __( 'Sort by average rating', 'woocommerce' ),

        'date'       => __( 'Sort by newness', 'woocommerce' ),

        'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),

        'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );

    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) == 'no' )
        unset( $catalog_orderby['rating'] );

    foreach ( $catalog_orderby as $id => $name )
        echo '<li>' . esc_attr( $name ) . '</li>';
?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Just switch out the echo `<option>` code with echo `<li>` code

Comment: You should add some explanation instead of a code-only answer

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately as it is no longer a select, it simply outputs the text, with no way to choose an option and deliver the result (through GET) You can see the sort of drop down I'm dealing with on the bottom of this page http://woo.browsepress.com/shop/

Comment: You will need to add javascript if you want a UL to handle click events.  The codrops demo you link above has the javascript